# How to check the constraints of a table in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I wanted to view the properties of a table in SSMS.
I have seen that 
'Highlighting the table name' and clicking on something gives the entire details about the table like the column description, constraint name and its description, etc.

Can someone tell me how to do that using SSMS?

Comment: it's Alt+F1 - shortcut has been set for `sp_help`

Comment: Thank You so much!!! You saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also find `exec sp_columns` with your table name quite useful

Answer (score 9):

Click on the plus symbol beside the table name. Folders for the columns, indexes and constraints etc will appear. Click on the plus beside the Constraints folder and any constraints on the table will be displayed.

If you wish to view details of the constraint. Right Click on it and Click 'Script Constraint as' - 'Create to' - 'New query Window'.

Comment: I added a unique constraint via `UNIQUE(Name)` when I created the table. Do you know why that doesn't show in the Constraints folder?